# how to copy text of file to ram (to do paste later)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, clipboard, ram

I would like to copy the content of a file (string) to my ram memory. As in copy of a text so I can do paste later.

Example:
I have a file name: `my_pub_key.pub` and inside there's big amount of chars. Every time I highlight the text and do copy and later paste - I get partial of the string.

Is there a (theoretical) way to do something like this:

```
root@my-ip: copy-to-ram < ~/.ssh/my_pub_key.pub
```

Comment: How large is this file? What you describe sounds like a bug in whatever desktop environment you are using, the clipboard should have this issue.

Comment: You can copy to the clipboard with something like `xsel` or `xclip` (or `wl-copy` on wayland), e.g.,`xsel -b < ~/.ssh/my_pub_key.pub`: but if you're having trouble using the clipboard for this in general, it's not clear this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to avoid any installation one can do:

```
cat ~/.ssh/my_pub_key.pub > /dev/clipboard
```

and you'll have it ready for a paste.